# Failed to resolve github libraries Android gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In recent days I'm getting failed to resolve github libraries for so many popular libraries. I know it generally happens when the library is suspended or not available. But i tried it for so many libraries. And getting same result. But doesn't mean every libraries don't work. Some works.

For example..

I tried it for PhotoView..

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
```

In the release page the latest version was 2.0.0

I get same thing for so many other libraries. I think last week I updated the gradle. So is that why I'm getting this problem for some libraries..

Or what can be the problem..

I'm also using all maven urls for all libraries as mentioned in the docs file..

Comment: Post the error text you are getting..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you added this root **`build.gradle`** file (Not your <s>**module**</s> **`build.gradle`**  file):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

**`FYI`**

New version has been released, You can try with

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: When I started android project. It was buildscript > repositories. Changed it to allprojects > repositories as you mentioned. And it worked. Thank you so much man...